# Running SSIS packages outside 2016 SSDT IDE using DTEXEC.exe

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Now that SQL Server 2016 Developer edition is free to download and develop with, I'm wondering if anyone knows if users are able to run SSIS packages using DTExec?  I ask because I thought that the Developer edition of SQL Server 2016 was comparable to the Enterprise edition - yet I'm running into errors about running packages outside of SSDT.

Have I just configured something incorrectly, or is this the case with the Developer edition?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, SQL Server 2016 Developer edition does support running packages outside of the SSDT Visual Studio IDE.

To resolve my issue, I uninstalled SQL Server 2012/14/16 and reinstalled only 2016.  To be clear, just specifying the DTExec.exe in the 130 folder didn't help me overcome the original error, so I'm unsure how the reinstall of 2016+SSDT fixed the issue.